# Accessing get method data in Django Template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

I have read docs and other things, tried many tuts but still no luck. What I am trying to achieve is to show a custom error message.

I have this: `/?message=success`

And want to access this data in my Django template

```
class mysite(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(mysite, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(mysite, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

How I am accessing it in my template file:

`{{ message }}`

This gives no output. What I need is **success** to be read. Then I will do a conditional block on its base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `message` to the template context by changing your `get_context_data` method to

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(mysite, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['message'] = self.request.GET.get('message', '') # default to empty string if not in GET data
    return context
```

Then access message in your template with:

```
{{ message }}
```

Alternatively, make sure you are using the [request template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request), to make the `request` object available in your templates.

Then in your template, you can access the GET data with:

```
{{ request.GET }}
```

and the message parameter with:

```
{{ request.GET.message }}
```